# Multiple MODAL VIEW controller change base modal to FULL SCREEN after ROTATION

Tags: ipad, rotation, ios6, modalviewcontroller, screen-size

This has been troubling me for quite a while, and I have done so much research on this, but could't find an answer. My first time posting a question here, please correct/forgive me if I make a mistake.

Environment: iPad, iOS 6.0

Problem: Base modal view change to full screen after rotation.

Description: I have a full screen application running currently showing a modal view controller. From the showing modal view, I display another modal view by doing:

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
//[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

While the second view is appearing, and I rotate the iPad device. The base(first) modal view becomes full screen, and the topmost(second) modal view stays in formSheet style. (rotate correctly)

I can fix this by adding modal view to navigationController, but I want to keep it in modal view.

Any one knows a fix? I believe this person here is having the same problem:
[ios 6 Incorrect modal view size after rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599621/ios-6-incorrect-modal-view-size-after-rotation)

Btw, everything works fine in iOS 5. Apple changed the way rotation works in iOS 6.
Thanks,
-peter

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution for this problem. Set the last modal view's presentation style to UIModalPresentationCurrentContext before you present it.

Like this:

vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

This solves the base modal view change size after rotate the iPad screen.

Originally answered by people on [Apple Dev forum](http://devforums.apple.com/message/748486).

Comment: FWIW, this worked great, but I had to set this inside the child view controller, I couldn't set it in prepareForSegue from the presentingVC.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and used the code in [iOS 6: Parent modal's modalPresentationStyle ignored after rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347906/ios-6-parent-modals-modalpresentationstyle-ignored-after-rotation) worked like a charm